# fastest way to create numpy 2d array of indices

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I want to create a numpy 2d array containning the cells indices, for example  such 2x2 mat can be created using :

```
np.array([[[0,0],[0,1]],[[1,0],[1,1]]])
```

In other words cell at index `i,j` should contain the list `[i,j]`.

I could make a nested loop to do it c way but i am wondering if there is a fast pythonic way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For performance with NumPy, I would suggest an array initialization based approach -

```
def indices_array(n):
    r = np.arange(n)
    out = np.empty((n,n,2),dtype=int)
    out[:,:,0] = r[:,None]
    out[:,:,1] = r
    return out
```

For a generic `(m,n,2)` shaped output, we need some modifications :

```
def indices_array_generic(m,n):
    r0 = np.arange(m) # Or r0,r1 = np.ogrid[:m,:n], out[:,:,0] = r0
    r1 = np.arange(n)
    out = np.empty((m,n,2),dtype=int)
    out[:,:,0] = r0[:,None]
    out[:,:,1] = r1
    return out
```

**Note:** Also, read - **2019 addendum** later on in this post for perf. boost with large `m`, `n`.

Sample run -

```
In [145]: n = 3

In [146]: indices_array(n)
Out[146]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2]]])
```

If you needed a `2` columns `2D` array, simply reshape -

```
In [147]: indices_array(n).reshape(-1,2)
Out[147]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [141]: n = 100   
     ...: out1 = np.array(list(product(range(n), repeat=2))).reshape(n,n,2)
     ...: out2 = indices_array(n)
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
     ...: 
True

# @Ofek Ron's solution
In [26]: %timeit np.array(list(product(range(n), repeat=2))).reshape(n,n,2)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop

In [27]: # @Brad Solomon's soln    
    ...: def ndindex_app(n):
    ...:    row, col = n,n
    ...:    return np.array(list(np.ndindex((row, col)))).reshape(row, col, 2)
    ...: 

# @Brad Solomon's soln 
In [28]: %timeit ndindex_app(n)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.72 ms per loop

# Proposed earlier in this post
In [29]: %timeit indices_array(n)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.1 µs per loop

In [30]: 2690/12.1
Out[30]: 222.31404958677686
```

**`200x+`** speedup there for `n=100` with the initialization based one!

---

#### 2019 addendum

We can also use [`np.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) -

```
def indices_array_generic_builtin(m,n):
    return np.indices((m,n)).transpose(1,2,0)
```

Timings -

```
In [115]: %timeit indices_array_generic(1000,1000)
     ...: %timeit indices_array_generic_builtin(1000,1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.92 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop
```

Comment: is it faster than np.ndindex as well?

Comment: @OfekRon Added timings for all methods. Check it out!

Comment: what if the rewquested mat isnt square? e.g you are given rows ,cols counts as in the ndindex?

Comment: def create_indices(rows,cols):
    r = np.arange(rows)
    c = np.arange(cols)
    out = np.empty((rows,cols,2),dtype=int)
    out[:,:,0] = r[:,None]
    out[:,:,1] = c
    print out
    return out

Comment: @OfekRon Check out the just added `indices_array_generic`.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.array(list(product(range(n), repeat=2))).reshape(n,n,2)
```

this works

Comment: cell indices are lists, i needed 2d matrix contains cell indices at each cell... I agree that this turns out to be 3 dimensions but thats what i needed

Answer (score 1):

You want [`np.ndindex`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html).

```
def coords(row, col):
    return np.array(list(np.ndindex((row, col)))).reshape(row, col, 2)

coords(3, 2)
Out[32]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1]]])
```